# Is time.mktime timezone free in python?

Tags: python, datetime, time, timezone, epoch

I am trying to understand the nature of epoch, and its behavior. Below I tried the same date with 2 different timezone specific datetime with 1 naive datetime

```
import time
import pytz
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

pst = pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles')
t = datetime(year=2015, month=2, day=2)
t = pst.localize(t)
time.mktime(t.timetuple()) 
# outputs 1422864000.0


utc = pytz.utc
k = datetime(year=2015, month=2, day=2)
k = utc.localize(k)
time.mktime(k.timetuple())
# outputs 1422864000.0




o = datetime(year=2015, month=2, day=2)
time.mktime(o.timetuple())
# outputs 1422864000.0
```

They all have the same epoch, but this is surprising, since the same date in pst should be offset by 7 hours in reference to utc. Can someone explain this?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried running `help(time.mktime)` ? tl;dr `help(time.mktime)` outputs : `Convert a time tuple in local time to seconds since the Epoch.` which means, no it doesnt care what time zone, it assumes its local.

Comment: @TehTris so is the final epoch local time adjusted? or is it always utc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`time.mktime()` returns the same result because it receives almost (~`isdst`) the same input in all three cases:

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=2015, tm_mon=2, tm_mday=2, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=33, ..)
```

`.timetuple()` does not store utc offset. It is equivalent to the naive `datetime` object.

In general, "epoch" i.e., "seconds since epoch" does not depend on timezone. It is neither local time nor utc. Knowing the timestamp you can get both using `datetime.fromtimestamp` and `datetime.utcfromtimestamp` correspondingly.

If your local timezone is different from `'America/Los_Angeles'` (different utc offset) then all three time instances are different and therefore all three POSIX timestamps are different:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from datetime import datetime
import pytz # $ pip install pytz

pacific = pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles')
naive  = datetime(2015, 2, 2)
pacific_dt = pacific.localize(naive, is_dst=None)
print(pacific_dt.timestamp())

utc_dt = naive.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
print(utc_dt.timestamp())

print(naive.timestamp()) #NOTE: interpret as local time
```

The last call may use `mktime(naive.timetuple())` internally.

#### Output

```
1422864000.0
1422835200.0
1422831600.0
```

Note: all three timestamps are different.

To get POSIX timestamp on older Python versions, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/4279).